# Java DataInputStream length

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating a file server application for school assignment. What I currently have is a simple `Client` class that sends an image through TCP and a `Server` class that receives it and writes it to the file.

this is my client code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        File file = new File("hot.jpg");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte sendData[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fin.read(sendData);

        outToServer.write(sendData, 0, sendData.length);
        clientSocket.close();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");
    }
}
```

and this is my server code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());

        byte[] receivedData = new byte[61500]; // <- THIS NUMBER

        for(int i = 0; i < receivedData.length; i++)
            receivedData[i] = dis.readByte();

        connectionSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("received.jpg");
        fos.write(receivedData);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

My question is how to get the size of the file that is being sent. If you check the `Server` code you'll see that I've hardcoded the number i.e. 61500 at the moment. How can I retrieve this number dynamically?

Or, am I doing this the wrong way? What an alternative solution would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add one "length field" before sending the file. *(Note that since you read the file to memory the maximum size of the file can be ~2GB.)*

---

Before sending the file write the length of the file:

```
  outToServer.writeInt(sendData.length);
```

And when receiving read the length first and use it as a length:

```
  int dataLength = dis.readInt()
  byte[] receivedData = new byte[dataLength];
```

---

A better way would be **not** to read the file into memory first but to transfer it directly from the `FileInputStream` - then you could transfer bigger files!

Comment: I don't see where I read the file into memory before sending it? Where is it and how can I avoid it?

Comment: @David Weng: At the point where you use '<- THIS NUMBER' you are allocating enough memory for the entire file. You rarely need to do that, and it doesn't scale to even moderately large files.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the length, using readFully() is much more efficient than reading a byte at a time.

In this case, you don't need to know the length, you can write the loop to read/write as much data as you get.

```
InputStream is = connectionSocket.getInputStream();

byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
int len;
while((len = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
    fos.write(bytes, 0, len);
```

You can avoid reading the whole file into memory by copying the data as you read it.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
int len;
while((len = fis.read(bytes)) > 0)
    os.write(bytes, 0, len);
```

You can use Apache [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).copy() to perform the copy from one stream to another if you wish.

This approach has the advantage that the file can be any size (greater than 2 GB). Using an array is limited to 2 GB (and uses more memory)

Comment: @codymanix, its basically a code copy of the first example. What doesn't make sense?